# which loaders to use for js.node file

Tags: webpack, electron

I'm building my app on top of [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate)

Webpack, React and Redux and all front-end library works fine.

I would like to include WebChimera.js in my app: [wcjs-prebuilt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wcjs-prebuilt).

wcjs-prebuilt containts a .js.node file. Webpack warns me that I need a loader for this. I tried file and raw loaders they did work fine ( node loader didnt work), but when I looked at the file in the dev tools it just exported a string containing raw binary.

Should I use Webpack to bundle my js.node files, and `import` it with js?
And if yes, what loaders in which order is needed for this type?

When loaded with only raw-loader, the error in devtools was:

```
  Uncaught TypeError: _wcjsPrebuilt2.default is not a function
client.js?207a:53 [HMR] connected
```

Comment: Can you try https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-loader ?

Comment: I tried that but gave me: Uncaught Error: Cannot open .../electron-react-boilerplate/node_modules/wcjs-prebuilt/bin/WebChimera.js.node: Error: [object Object]: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Ok, hard to say. Maybe you could ask at **electron-react-boilerplate** directly.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is easy. I had to use webpack externals.

```
  externals: [
    // put your node 3rd party libraries which can't be built with webpack here (mysql, mongodb, and so on..)
  ]
```

:)